# script get killed when encoding process

Tags: python, nvidia-jetson-nano

i want to minimize my face recognition system from PC to Jetson nano.

after the system done encoding some images in dataset, the system freeze for a while and get killed.

this my code:

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import platform

def running_on_jetson_nano():
   return platform.machine() == "aarch64"

def get_jetson_gstreamer_source(capture_width=1280, capture_height=720, display_width=1280, display_height=720, framerate=60, flip_method=0):
    return (f'nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), ' +
            f'width=(int){capture_width}, height=(int){capture_height}, ' +                
            f'format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction){framerate}/1 ! ' +
            f'nvvidconv flip-method={flip_method} ! ' +
            f'video/x-raw, width=(int){display_width}, height=(int){display_height}, format=(string)BGRx ! ' +
            'videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink'
        )
if running_on_jetson_nano():
   video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(get_jetson_gstreamer_source(), cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
else:
   video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


path = './dataset'
folders = [f for f in glob.glob(path + '**/*', recursive=True)]

known_face_encodings = []
known_face_names = []

for f in folders:
    names = f.split('/')[2]
    print('encoding file : {}'.format(names))
    for images_f in glob.glob(f + '**/*.jpg'):

        images = face_recognition.load_image_file(images_f)
        location = face_recognition.face_locations(images)
        images_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(images, known_face_locations = location)[0]
        known_face_encodings.append(images_encoding)
        known_face_names.append(names)
```

does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Examine system logs, I'm guessing you are running out of memory and the OOM killer takes you.

Comment: @tripleee so is that mean i need more memory? or is there any other way to do without upgrade memory?

Comment: Start by examining the system logs to establish whether my guess is correct. There are almost certainly ways to avoid getting more memory but typically they are much more involved than simply spending a few dozen bucks.

Comment: yes, i'm running out of memory @tripleee